# Jquery click on interactive image-map not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I have an interactive image-map on my website.
The html is:

```
<div id="italy-map" class="affiancato verticalmenteAllineato">
    <div id="region-map">
        <img src="./Immagini/transparent.gif"  title="Clicca su una regione per vedere le cliniche!" 
             alt="Clicca su una regione per vedere le cliniche!" usemap="#ItalyMap" /> 
    </div> 
</div>

<map id="ItalyMap"> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="1" alt="Valle d'Aosta" title="Valle de Aosta"   coords="47,56,48,76,14,86,1,65" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="2" alt="Piemonte" title="Piemonte"   coords="66,34,73,46,74,67,79,84,70,94,85,106,95,122,78,133,58,128,49,153,32,154,7,136,11,119,-2,103,7,96,19,96,21,83,48,75,48,57,60,42" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="3" alt="Liguria" title="Liguria"   coords="131,156,105,134,108,131,90,126,69,137,74,133,65,131,56,141,49,157,47,154,40,154,31,165,35,169,48,170,75,141,89,137,95,139" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="4" alt="Lombardia" title="Lombardia"   coords="101,122,88,105,75,107,72,89,84,84,73,65,78,47,92,63,105,27,113,40,132,39,137,23,157,35,148,39,152,48,142,64,147,57,149,64,162,65,151,79,159,80,158,84,153,85,160,95,183,109,153,107,154,110,130,104,130,99,117,103,113,100,102,108,105,117" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="5" alt="Trentino-Alto Adigio" title="Trentino-Alto Adige"  coords="150,64,166,66,162,73,176,70,176,63,190,51,192,59,196,47,203,50,203,43,197,37,197,29,210,27,210,19,212,26,224,20,213,12,213,-3,199,5,176,6,166,17,152,12,141,17,146,14,145,25,136,24,141,30,154,34,148,40,151,45,146,59" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="6" alt="Veneto" title="Veneto"   coords="218,116,210,114,209,107,197,110,190,113,177,108,155,88,157,82,160,67,177,74,182,52,203,49,205,40,199,35,225,19,233,23,232,35,219,43,223,51,223,61,229,67,242,67,247,72,220,86,218,101,228,112" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="7" alt="Friuli-Venezia Giulia" title="Friuli-Venezia Giulia"   coords="277,78,272,73,246,75,242,65,227,66,223,62,221,44,238,22,272,32,265,42,271,52,270,64,279,72" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="8" alt="Emilia-Romagna" title="Emilia-Romagna"   coords="236,162,231,157,214,161,210,171,189,158,196,152,177,143,178,148,165,153,125,132,109,138,99,127,103,115,108,100,131,103,144,107,148,111,153,110,215,111,215,139" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="9" alt="Toscana" title="Toscana"   coords="185,236,196,224,200,212,205,198,214,193,215,169,196,167,193,152,181,147,164,156,125,132,120,140,132,153,146,191,150,208,151,213,144,216,133,217,133,221,142,223,149,220,145,216,152,213,168,225,177,238" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="10" alt="Umbria" title="Umbria"   coords="228,238,253,221,256,217,242,212,235,186,228,186,220,178,210,179,212,189,206,201,203,217,205,226,212,224,225,237" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="11" alt="Lazio" title="Lazio"   coords="276,298,282,277,264,270,254,260,242,256,247,249,258,250,258,248,250,246,249,231,260,229,254,221,226,240,212,226,206,228,202,217,197,220,196,232,188,240,205,260,215,267,219,274,245,293" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="12" alt="Marche" title="Marche"   coords="215,169,232,186,237,189,240,210,255,216,259,227,279,213,264,174,253,175,239,158,234,167,222,157,221,155,209,166" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="13" alt="Abruzzo" title="Abruzzo"   coords="312,255,279,213,258,227,261,232,250,230,252,245,259,250,254,251,246,251,245,255,263,267,284,274,289,272,289,269,296,262,301,267,301,271,305,270" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="14" alt="Molise" title="Molise"  coords="328,261,315,257,305,271,302,268,297,264,290,270,291,272,283,275,284,284,284,288,285,292,290,281,303,289,321,283,318,278,326,274" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="15" alt="Campania" title="Campania"  coords="342,360,349,346,331,316,341,312,342,305,331,301,331,298,320,283,301,290,290,282,286,289,274,298,285,317,295,317,303,329,316,328,321,348" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="16" alt="Puglia" title="Puglia"   coords="329,261,360,255,368,266,367,272,359,280,364,289,411,310,420,319,440,325,445,331,452,338,454,346,454,359,450,370,438,363,427,342,413,344,399,331,394,341,385,334,386,322,373,321,365,311,363,309,354,306,360,308,362,306,353,297,354,299,341,305,330,296,320,278,327,277" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="17" alt="Basilicata" title="Basilicata"   coords="351,361,343,356,351,346,335,317,342,313,343,306,359,304,361,310,358,312,375,321,387,324,387,336,395,339,386,351,376,350,372,363,361,363,359,359" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="18" alt="Calabria" title="Calabria"  href="#a" coords="363,466,345,462,345,447,353,438,356,422,367,415,361,405,363,391,352,364,355,357,372,364,378,349,383,351,378,371,404,387,404,410,387,416,381,428,385,433" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="19" alt="Sardegna" title="Sardegna"   coords="92,418,96,400,110,406,121,377,117,346,124,329,109,292,91,302,75,313,62,310,58,323,68,339,66,362,72,364,61,402,78,416" /> 
    <area shape="poly" data-id="20" alt="Sicilia" title="Sicilia"   coords="322,529,299,521,286,507,271,505,237,482,228,481,219,472,226,451,238,453,249,447,269,456,296,459,309,449,323,453,340,445,344,450,329,474,325,489,334,508,332,513" /> 
</map>
```

The above html is affected by the following css:

```
#italy-map {
   width: 458px;
   height: 531px;
   background:url(../Immagini/cartinaItalia.gif) no-repeat;
   z-index:100;
   margin: 0px 0px 35px 0%;
}

#region-map{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index:105;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}

#region-map img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.sprite_region {
   background: url(../Immagini/sprite_map.gif) no-repeat;
   width: 460px;
   height: 531px;
   z-index: 110;
}

.sprite_region_all{background:none; z-index:110;}
.sprite_region_1 {background-position:-8280px 0px;}
.sprite_region_2 {background-position:-5060px  0px;}
.sprite_region_3 {background-position:-3220px  0px;}
.sprite_region_4 {background-position:-3680px 0px;}
.sprite_region_5 {background-position:-7360px 0px;}
.sprite_region_6 {background-position:-8740px 0px;}
.sprite_region_7 {background-position:-2300px 0px;}
.sprite_region_8 {background-position:-1840px 0px;}
.sprite_region_9 {background-position:-6900px 0px;}
.sprite_region_10{background-position:-7820px 0px;}
.sprite_region_11{background-position:-2760px 0px;}
.sprite_region_12{background-position:-4140px 0px;}
.sprite_region_13{background-position:0px 0px;}
.sprite_region_14{background-position:-4600px 0px;}
.sprite_region_15{background-position:-1380px 0px;}
.sprite_region_16{background-position:-5520px 0px;}
.sprite_region_17{background-position:-460px 0px;}
.sprite_region_18{background-position:-920px 0px;}
.sprite_region_19{background-position:-5980px 0px;}
.sprite_region_20{background-position:-6440px 0px;}
```

Then this is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
     var $ = jQuery;
     var map = $("#italy-map");
     var region_map = $("#region-map");

     $("area[data-id]").mouseover(function () {
        var r = $(this);
        var id = r.attr("data-id");
        region_map.removeClass();
        region_map.addClass("sprite_region sprite_region_" + id);
     });

     $("area[data-id]").mouseout(function () {
        region_map.removeClass();
     });

     $("area[data-id]").click(function () {
        var r = $(this);
        var id = r.attr("data-id");
        var title = r.attr("title");
        inviaRegione(title);
     });
});
```

This code works good on IE and Firefox, but it doesn't work on Chrome. On chrome the javascript functions are not triggered. 
I thought that the problem was the z-index of the html elements but i tried some other values and combinations without any results.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `id` attribute to `name` in the map tag. Chrome seems to dislike it when map has its name in an id attribute. Your map opening tag should become this:

```
<map name="ItalyMap">
```